# Como hacer un triggerbot con la libreria de autoit en vb.net

Tags: vb.net

La verdad es que he buscado por todos lados y no encuentro como hacer una instrucción funcional.

Alguna idea?

```
Dim AU As Autoitlib
Private Sub Shoot_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Shoot.Tick
        AU.MouseClick(AU.PixelSearch(158, 54, 158, 54, 14091270))
    End Sub
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. Sería interesante saber cual es el problema con el código que nos enseñas. No funciona? Te lanza alguna excepción?

Comment: lo que pasa es que necesito hacer una instrucción en la cual busque por el color del pixel 14091270 en decimal  en los rangos que le doy y si es cierto osea si lo encuentra haga un click en el mouse no me lanza ningun error solo no cumple la funcion por eso preguntaba si alguien tenia idea o habia trabajado anteriormente con la libreria de autoit en net

Answer (score 0):

Para PixelSearch puedes usar una adaptación de OpenCV: 
http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

Y para mover el mouse tienes SetCursorPos de Pinvoke: https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.setcursorpos

EDIT: Disculpa que no había visto que quieres enviar un click en vez de mover el mouse, que es triggerbot y no aimbot.

Entonces necesitas otra función, pero también es de pinvoke:

Pinvoke mouse event: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.mouse_event

Espero que te ayude!